# data transfer from android device to pc using bluetooth and sockets

Tags: android, sockets, bluetooth

I need to do a data transfer from my android device to my pc using bluetooth.
Actually, I think the best solution for this is to create a client socket for my android device and a server socket for my pc to realise this data transfer and see the results. any helpfull stuff to offer please?

I'm working on Android Studio

Comment: You need to provide some code of what you have done so far.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to send data via bluetooth you need to implement BluetoothSocket logic. You can find some tutorials for that in these links;

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-bluetooth-scanner-with-androids-bluetooth-api--cms-24084

http://www.elecfreaks.com/677.html

For detailed detailed google doc [click here](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html)