# Is it possible to receive data through bluetooth without running app in 2 devices and without having socket connection

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have refered so many articles.

[How to receive images via Bluetooth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43930776/how-to-receive-images-via-bluetooth)

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BluetoothChat

[How to receive data via Bluetooth on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39296807/how-to-receive-data-via-bluetooth-on-android)

[data transfer from android device to pc using bluetooth and sockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35888746/data-transfer-from-android-device-to-pc-using-bluetooth-and-sockets)

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth

[How to send and receive data in Android Programming using bluetooth without pairing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6494006/how-to-send-and-receive-data-in-android-programming-using-bluetooth-without-pair)

Comment: can you elaborate what exactly you wanna do

Comment: In my android app ..if any other device sends data through bluetooth I need to accept those files in my app and receive those files and store in local db @MirzaAhmedBaig

Comment: Hey you can't directly read data from another app over Bluetooth

Comment: @MirzaAhmedBaig Thank you..Then What is the solution? I need to use socket connection?

Answer (score 1):

For data transfer between two devices, you have to implement Bluetooth Sockets and connect to that receiving device. You can find the details here.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth

Just try to use Demo projects on it.